# eclipse shows unrecognizable characters in the console

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers. I found the compilation message output in the console window contains some unrecognizable characters such below.

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project test ****

make all 
Building file: ../a.cpp
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"a.d" -MT"a.d" -o"a.o" "../a.cpp"
../a.cpp:4: error: non-member function 鈥榲oid f(bool&)鈥?cannot have cv-qualifier
make: *** [a.o] Error 1
```

Could anyone please let me know how to correct this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with your encoding... look to see what your encoding is in the preferences, under General->Workspace. (I'm on a Mac, mine says "MacRoman")

Comment: I tried to change it before; it did not show any effect though.

Comment: Thanks Luis, I just accepted some answers. Still quite new to the website. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check the encoding of the individual files that you are compiling.  In addition to a default workspace encoding (mentioned by @adam_0), there can be overridden encodings on each file.

Right click on the file and goto properties.  You should see the file encoding there.  My guess is that you have at least one of your source files set to a encoding that is incompatible with the compiler.  Try setting everything to UTF8 and see if that helps.